# Which option do I need to select before releasing my app to google play?

Tags: google-play, android-app-signing

I created signed app bundle using VS code and I have its keystore file.Which option should I select to release app bundle to playstore.Is It okay to select let google create and sign app my option while having a keystore file with me?

[image: Play store capture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should choose first option if you want Google to manage the signing key to sign your app. You will still need to sign the application using the keystore that you've generated but this will be your upload key.

In case you lose your upload key, you can contact the support team to get a new one, only if you have enrolled in app signing by google play.

If you want to manage your signing key yourself, you can choose the second option. You'll need to sign further updates to your application using the same signing key. If you lose the signing key, you will not be able to publish further updates to the application.